# trueHeading reference model

Tags: ios

What reference model is used when computing trueHeading, CLHeading in iOS?

trueHeading
The heading (measured in degrees) relative to true north. (read-only)

@property(readonly, nonatomic) CLLocationDirection trueHeading

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLHeading_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLHeading/trueHeading

Comment: What do you mean? Reference model?

Comment: Android class GeomagneticField uses the World Magnetic Model produced by the United States National Geospatial-Intelligence Agency  http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/WMM/DoDWMM.shtml. 

What is the equivalent for iOS?

Comment: What are you looking for, degrees to true north is degrees no matter what. You can also use `magneticHeading` if you mean that. It's all in the developers guide you mentioned. Maybe i just don't understand you...

Comment: In order to get degrees to true north you need to add declination to magneticHeading. Declination depends on the location, it is different for different longitude, latitude and altitude. But to get declination for different locations you have to base that on some model. That is what I am looking for. The model used as a reference.

Comment: The docs for CLHeading says it needs the current location to calculate the true heading. I guess thats your reference point. I cannot find anything on the model used to calculate that correction.